# Microphone picks up itself after assistant is done talking while waiting for user input

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm having an interesting problem where the microphone for the google assistant is picking up the end of the previous message that the assistant was speaking as a response by the user. At the moment this is an issue **only** on android phones, not the home mini. It seems this only happens when the message it's speaking is lengthy, most of mine are >25 seconds.

So for example the message will be the last 5 of 30 seconds of an app.ask() with "Would you like to hear this repeated?" and the Microphone might pick up "like to hear this repeated" and then attempt to process that and of course that's unexpected.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or ways around it? I'm using SSML in a simpleResponse (Node.js 1.0, haven't migrated yet.) so I tried inserting a break for a couple seconds at the end which didn't solve it, as well as saying something after the longer duration break at the end hoping the microphone would open after but that didn't solve it. Anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot it?

Additional info:

Microphone is not converting it's shape until after the speaking is done but then is subsequently picking up it's own spoken word from before the icon converted.

I tried a bit more troubleshooting and got it to be a bit more deterministic. There are two ways of getting into the action. One is asking to speak to it and the other is asking if the action can provide data that would subsequently have been asked for after starting to speak with it. (Explicit invocation, vs explicit invocation while calling an action.) This only occurs when one is asking to speak with it and subsequently asking for the data

Ensuring each `<sub alias=...></sub>` tag has a value associated with it `<sub alias = "Yes">No</sub>` did not solve either.

My code has multiple sub alias tags (>10) in the readout. Compiling them all into one large alias block did not solve either.

Confirmed this is occurring on other android devices.

Comment: Just tested on an iPhone and did not have this issue either. Have not had the opportunity to test this on a different android phone.

Comment: When you're running it, you should see the microphone icon at the bottom of the screen transition between active and inactive. Do you see the icon transition early?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Nope, it does not. The icon transitions at the correct time after the speech has finished but begins filling in data from the end of the message.

Comment: So I tried a bit more troubleshooting and got it to be a bit more deterministic. There are two ways of getting into the action. One is asking to speak to it and the other is asking if the action can provide data that would subsequently have been asked for after starting to speak with it. (Explicit invocation, vs explicit invocation while calling an action.) This only occurs when one is asking to speak with it and subsequently asking for the data.

Comment: Can you provide some example dialog?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IMjBtJy 

This would be the end of the speech: from right before it "...<break time="300ms"/><sub alias= "Density Altitude"></sub><sub alias= "5 hundred"></sub><break time="300ms"/><sub alias= " Field is V F R"></sub></speak>"

Comment: I'm not sure if your SSML is fitting the technical specs since you have `<sub alias="...` but you don't provide a value for the tag, as shown in the doc: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

Comment: Can you add values for each `<sub>` and then see if you still have issues

Comment: Same issue with each <sub> getting a value, a snippit again: ...`<sub alias= \"Dew Point\">a</sub><sub alias= \"1 7 \">a</sub><break time=\"300ms\"/> <sub alias= \"Altimeter\">a</sub> <sub alias= \"1 Zero 1 5 MilliBAR's\">a</sub><break time=\"300ms\"/><sub alias= \"Density Altitude\">a</sub><sub alias= \"1 thousandniner hundred\">a</sub><break time=\"300ms\"/><break time=\"300ms\"/> Would you like this repeated or a different airport?</speak>"`

Comment: Compiling all the aliases into one big alias block did not solve either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not being able to solve this problem directly.

My solution since I had a rich response was to simply add a second (there can only be two at the time of writing) simple response to the Rich Response after the first which ensured the mic wouldn't pick up itself.

```
app.buildRichResponse()
    // Create a basic card and add it to the rich response
    .addSimpleResponse(output[0])
    .addBasicCard(app.buildBasicCard(output[1])
        .setTitle(title)
        .setSubtitle(subtitle)
        .addButton("Online Link", "URL HERE")
    )
    .addSimpleResponse("Would you like this repeated?")
```